# Android DataBase is Locked by other thread

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on android sqLite database in which I am not able to insert record into DataBase.
In code I open database only once at the time of launch application, and I set there reference to my Application class variable so that I can access database from any part of code and this works fine.

Problem is: I can access the database, but I'm not able to beginTransaction. It does not give me any exception but `sqLiteDatabaseWrite.isDbLockedByOtherThreads()` returns `TRUE`. Also, in logcat there is one warning message:

> WARN/SQLiteDatabase(19006): database lock has not been available for
>   30 sec. Current Owner of the lock is 1. Continuing to wait in thread:
>   14

Any solutions ?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for being with me. Actually I resolved my issue. I started one SQLite DB operation by using `sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()` and I forgot to end this transaction. I resolved the issue by ending the transaction. To end the transaction I used the following code:

```
sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing same problem in android, thanks for your info.